# How to use PC keyboard during Remote Screen Sharing using Android app?

Tags: java, android, linux, adb, keyevent

We have a remote screen sharing option in our android app for Android TV devices. We use OEM API to trigger some of the key and button events by passing the constants defined in the [android.view.KeyEvent](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/KeyEvent) class. This works for number keys and cursor keys in keyboard but the KeyEvent constants for alphabets are limited to only uppercase letters, like **KEYCODE_A for 'A' key**. There are no constants for smallercase letters.

Tried using input text command. It works in the shell but doesn't work in the app -

```
String keyCommand = "input text " + character;
            Runtime runtime = Runtime.getRuntime();
            Process proc = runtime.exec(keyCommand);
            int waitFor = proc.waitFor();
```

Exit value returned is 1.

Is there any other way to process the Uppercase and lowercase letters events received from a Keyboard?

Edit: We are not using the KeyEvent class methods or constants directly as the input is not from a physical keyboard but from the keyboard of the PC in which the remote screen is viewed. Only the KeyEvent constant values are passed to OEM API for triggering the key/button.